# How to make backbone models inherit prototype from THREE.Object3D

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, three.js, underscore.js

I want to create a model that has all the Backbone.Model functionality (validation, defaults etc.) but also another prototype. Specifically, I want the prototype and constructor be from THREE.Object3d. i use threejs **r69** (latest)

Currently I do something like this:

```
var MyObj = new function(){...}
MyObj.prototype = Object.create(THREE.Object3D.prototype);
MyObj.prototype.constructor = THREE.Object3D;
```

How can I make MyObj to be a Backbone.Model instance while having the THREE.Object3d prototype, so that I can simply add it to a scene and just use it like a normal THREE.Object3d, all while not breaking the Backbone.Model interface?

When I try to use:

```
var MyObj = Backbone.Model.extend(THREE.Object3D.prototype);
```

I get the following error:

> DEPRECATED: Object3D's .eulerOrder has been moved to Object3D's .rotation.order.
>
> three.js:7306 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'order' of undefined

There are several attributes `undefined` but I'm not sure why that is? Why is rotation undefined?

**EDIT: see my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MJB/n872owog/1/)**. Open the console to see the errors!

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error, could you check http://jsfiddle.net/gogan82/062tunsu/1/ and fork if appropriate to include missing details?

Comment: @James: Updated the fiddle. also you used r54 in your fiddle, which is really old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do that by extending the `prototype` of Backbone.Model and then call the constructor function of `THREE.Object3D`. This could happen by doing :

```
var Object3DModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        _(this.prototype).extend(THREE.Object3D.prototype);
        THREE.Object3D.apply(this, arguments);
    }

});
```

I'm using `underscore` extend for extending the prototype here.

You can see [working jsbin](http://jsbin.com/mibegumuma/1/edit?js,console).

*Edit*

I just played around more and it seems that a better approach would be :

```
// Start with a constructor, calling the two constructors of the classes
var Object3DModel = function() {
  THREE.Object3D.apply(this, arguments);
  Backbone.Model.apply(this, arguments);
};

// Copy Object3D Prototype
Object3DModel.prototype = new THREE.Object3D();

// Append Backbone.Model prototype
var ref = new Backbone.Model();
for ( var name in ref ) {
  Object3DModel.prototype[name] = ref[name];
}
```

Because *THREE* library is using getters and setters, so the correct way to inherit them would be this one.

Anyway I created a [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/xeqimaxeru/1/edit?js,console,output) which has the basic functionality tested.

Comment: Nice this seems to work, a question though. Normally you would have `_.extend(...)` to be the function, in you jsbin you used: 
 `_(this.prototype).extend(THREE.Object3D.prototype);` how does `_(this.protoype).extend` work? to what do you pass `this.prototype`? I'd really like to know why "my approach" doesn't work aswell.

Comment: _.extend works similar to $.extend You can check docs [here](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) :) No time for further explanation now, will be back later.

Comment: yeah I mean. normally you use underscore like `_.FUNCTION`, where FUNCTION may be extend, or each and so on. but you used it differently like `_(this.prototype).FUNCTION`. the `.` operator comes after the `_()` which confuses me. shouldn't it be `_.extend(....)` ??

Comment: Oh you mean that. Well it's underscore chaining. It is also very well explained in [the docs](http://underscorejs.org/#chaining) :) It's the same as `_.extend(this.prototype, THREE.Object3D.prototype)`

Comment: The problem now is that the new object is not an instance of THREE.Object3D anymore, and thus all calls to Object3D functions don't work anymore.

Comment: Okay, will revise my answer tomorrow. Too much stuff on my plate today :)

Comment: Thanks. I had something similar to this, but then the Backbone.prototype wasn't working. I ended up using your solution but with `Object3DModel.prototype = Object.create(THREE.Object3D)`

Comment: Yes that would be more appropriate, since THREE is using the same way to extend it's own classes. I've never used THREE before, but I've had some experience with d3.js and it seems like you should be very careful when you do this. Actually I would suggest to you to have those two classes not inherited at all or at least run the tests of those libraries on your extended class if you use this in production.

Comment: yeah sure, I don't do this with the actual "3dObjects" (read: renderer objects) I use, but rather to some controller objects that belong to a scene. these objects I create here never get rendered in the first place, they're just existing to do other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you.

```
var myObj = Backbone.Model.extend(THREE.Object3D.prototype);
```

Comment: see my question again.